# Unable use any QWebSocket client basic example

Tags: c++, qt, websocket, osx-lion

Im unable to use any of the QWebSockets client examples listed here: 
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtwebsockets-examples.html
The application tries to open the localhost url, the socket gets stuck in QAbstractSocket::ConnectingState and

> qDebug() << m_webSocket.error();

returns QAbstractSocket::UnknownSocketError. Of course the 'connected' signal is never emitted.
I have qt 5.3 in a osx lion. I've got OpenSSL 1.0.1i and

> QSslSocket::supportsSsl() ;

returns true.

Im really out of ideas so if you got any ill be extremely grateful.

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I don't think ssl is the issue in this case.

I just ran the examples and it just worked fine. Which means there could be one of the following common problems (or there could be others I don't know about).

- The local port number 1234 is being used by other process. Which means, try editing `EchoClient client(QUrl(QStringLiteral("ws://localhost:1234")));` and replace `1234` with a number like `8888` or `9001` etc should solve the problem. Notice, you have to change port in both client and server program in that case. (Read next point to fully understand in case you don't understand what I am saying.)
- Run the client program while the corresponding server program is running. For example, when you are running `echoclient`, you are supposed to keep the `echoserver` running. If you are in windows or linux, you can do this by opening two Qt Creator process and running the `echoserver` first and then `echoclient`. If you are in Mac, you can't create two instances of Qt Creator (at least in Yosemite, I don't know about osx lion). You have to run the `echoserver` (and don't close the console), then open the `echoclient` project and Set echoclient as Active Project and  run.
- *(though not likely)* if you are opening a project, copying the cpp files from website and pasting it in your project and then compiling (instead of downloading it form Examples tab of your Qt Creator), then you may be missing configuration of .pro file. Just add `websockets` with `QT     += core` in the `.pro` file of the project.

If these are not the cases, then you can let me know and you can try posting in the [Qt forum](http://qt-project.org/forums) too in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of code working for me:

```
CSocketClient : public QWebSocket
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    CSocketClient();

protected slots:
    void SL_Connected();
    void SL_Disconnected();
};


CSocketClient::CSocketClient() : QWebSocket("MyApplication")
    {
    connect(this, &QWebSocket::connected, this, &OSocketWebGenogramClient::SL_Connected);
    connect(this, &QWebSocket::disconnected, this, &CSocketClient::SL_Disconnected);
    open(QUrl("ws://localhost:45002"));
    }

void
CSocketClient::SL_Connected()
    {
    qDebug() << "Connected to server on port" << localPort();
    }

void
CSocketClient::SL_Disconnected()
    {
    }
```